# How is common source NMOS stage with active current load realized in practice?

Tags: transistors, mosfet, amplifier, circuit-design, nmos

In a well known book about CMOS circuit design (Design of Analog CMOS Integrated Circuits) I found this example about a cascode stage with current source load.
[image]

The basic idea is, to replace the drain resistor Ro of the basic common source amplifier with an active load of high Ro (the current source) and so take advantage of the high (intrinsic) gain of the stage.

But, looking at the image I cannot imagine, how Vin can be chosen in order to make Id1=I1: I1 flows through M1 and M2, but Id1 is already determined by biasing Vin - so there is a conflict. How is such stage realized in practice?

By the way - this kind of "discrepancy" I observed already several times when trying to understand such circuits.

Comment: Not sure where your confusion comes from. In practice I1 is not exactly as specified, because the current source still has some output resistance. Also, there is usually a load driven by Vout, so the difference in current that is generated by M1 from a difference in Vin can escape to the load. Also, these amplifiers are usually designed to work with small signals. As such, I1 biases M2 and thus Vin and the actual signal is then some somewhat small deviation.

Comment: It seems like you are ignoring the fact that Id of the device can be controlled by sizing its aspect ratio (W/L) as well as vgs bias. Why would you not be able to design to match equivalent Id as the load current? In practice, all those variables would be designed up front. Not a fixed vgs and then some arbitrary current load that doesn't match it.

Comment: @pat: of course the currents Id1 and I1 can be made the same - but only theoretically. They will never be the same exactly and then the biasing M1 is somehow arbitrary, depending on the deviation.

Comment: @Uroc327: But when the next stage is a high impedance input (like the gate of a MOSFET) then there is nothing to escape.

Comment: @MichaelW. You haven't really explained about why you believe they won't be the same, could you elaborate in your question? In practice, the (not ideal) current load would be typically be realized by a pch cascode (possibly mirror, but not necessarily) and currents will be the same, but any device mismatches or process variations could easily force one branch into triode saturating the output voltage near a rail (and altering expected current). Feedback is commonly used to force branches to operate near the center of the output range and to be equal and in saturation.

Comment: @MichaelW sure there is. The gate has some capacitance. And because you look at small signals only, this additional current (dis-)charges the gate of that mosfet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*@pat: of course the currents Id1 and I1 can be made the same - but only theoretically. They will never be the same exactly and then the biasing M1 is somehow arbitrary, depending on the deviation.*

But in a practical realization, they are the same. Since where else would the current difference go, unless you have some kind of a load attached (none in your op)? However, the operating points will move around to make the currents equal.

edit*
I'll try to make the concept of feedback against process variation
more clear in a set of contrived simulations (hypothetical models) I built.

[image]

1. Bottom Left is a basic CS configuration using pch as a (nonideal) current load. First, ignore the feedback resistors there, and assume no feedback or resistors (open loop).
2. In the figure above it, I designed the operating point (VGS) so that the output is Vdd/2 and the currents intersect at a desired point. That is op2.
3. In the same diagram I show the effect of process variations, by altering the Vt values. Notice op1 and op3 and op4 will move the operating point all over the place and every bad case has devices in triode. BUT-- currents in upper and lower branch are still equal (op1:op4), just the desired current (and hence voltage out) op has moved.
4. The effect of this in time domain is shown in in top right figure. Only one (blue) graph shows a good signal amplification. The rest are op1, op3, and op4 where devices are in triode and the linear gain no longer works.
5. In practice, we usually don't design amplifiers to operate as linear amplifiers without any feedback. The gain of the amp without feedback (~50dB) is fairly high, and not controlled well.
6. If I add some kind of feedback (closed loop), notice good things start to happen. Now the devices are all operating with close to the same vout as we would want. The other waveforms are no longer dead (or saturated near voltage rails) as gain is staying operational across variations. We've also desensitized the circuit significantly against the process variations.

Still not a perfectly linear response, but I just threw it together to demonstrate the concept of feedback here. Notice also, the currents in both devices are always the same here (even with huge process variations) feedback or not, but it is just the operating point that is changing. Another big thing that is done to reduce sensitivity to channel length modulation effects is use larger output resistance configurations (stacking, cascoding, or increasing ch. lengths).

Here's another example of feedback benefits, using a blocking capacitor, you don't even have to set vgs. The feedback will self set the bias.

[image]

Comment: I tried hard to simulate this scenario and observed, that due to the small slope of the output characteristics due to channel length modulation the voltages Uds tend to flip between triode and saturated regime. I cannot imagine, that in practice the microstructure can be fabricated such accurate, that both Uds are the same. What kind of feedback are you talking about? When I do feedback using an OpAmp (just for simulation) I have no signal amplification anymore. So can you explain the feedback which is used typically?

Comment: An op amp with feedback does have signal amplification.

Comment: With such feedback it is no problem to set an operating point. So it means in practice such circuit would be driven always with feedback.

Comment: My mistake was the wrong assumption, that voltage gain would be dramatically reduced by such feedback. However, using a high value for R2 results in high gain anyway...you opened my eyes!

Answer (score 1):

> But, looking at the image I cannot imagine, how Vin can be chosen in order to make Id1=I1: I1 flows through M1 and M2, but Id1 is already determined by biasing Vin - so there is a conflict. How is such stage realized in practice?

The idea is that I1 is connected in parallel with the drain resistance of M2. That resistance is not infinite. I1 is a nominal current. The output voltage changes, since the output impedance (M2.rD) is finite and variable. Conversely, it is the M2 slightly varying drain impedance that develops a variable output voltage across M2's drain impedance that also acts as the load impedance, assuming I1 is an ideal source.

The M1 would be biased to be saturated at the nominal value of I1. As M1's VGS goes below that operating point, its drain impedance goes up, and so goes the drain impedance of M2: the output node is pulled up by the source I1. As M1's gate goes above the operating point, its output impedance gets lower, and the output node is pulled down by the lowering impedance of drain of M2.

I1 is what sets the operating current. You can set the gate voltages to whatever you want, but as long as both transistors conduct well enough, there'll be exactly I1 flowing through them, assuming that no other load is connected. Otherwise, KCL would be fiction :)

What really happens is that M2's drain is not infinite resistance. Or, rather, the M2+M1 series connection doesn't have infinite resistance, and it is this variable resistance that the output voltage is developed around.

You set the bias Vb so that M1 stabilizes the source voltage for M1, and thus its VDS, isolating M1's drain impedance from the output node, and set's M1's drain voltage to make it operate as a variable resistor.